# Retrieving SSM Parameter store secret in AWS EKS (pods)

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-secrets-manager

Can someone please help me to fetch the `aws-ssm-parameter-store` secret into an AWS EKS `pod`?

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: aws-secrets
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:
    objects: |
        - objectName: "/abc/myparameter"
          objectType: "ssmparameter"
```

```html
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: agent-config
data:
  agent.yaml: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols: 
          grpc:
    processors:
    exporters:
      otlp:
        endpoint: "opentelemetrycollector.default.svc.cluster.local:4317"
        insecure: true
    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: []
          exporters: [otlp]
---
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: aws-secrets
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:
    objects: |
        - objectName: "/abc/myparameter"
          objectType: "ssmparameter"
          objectAlias: otel_enalbed_status
---                    
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    spec:
      containers:

      - name: myapp
        image: quay.io/jpkroehling/generate-span-java:0.1.0
            {{- if otel_enalbed_status }}
      - name: agent
        image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.18.0
        args:
        - --config=/conf/agent.yaml
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /conf
          name: agent-config
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: agent.yaml
            path: agent.yaml
          name: agent-config
        name: agent-config
```

Here, I would like to store the value of my parameter "/abc/myparameter" in a variable and be able to use it in another part of the code. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what is the issue you are facing with this?

Comment: I am getting error that,    "Parse error at Line: 49  - Function "ssm" not defined

Comment: Can you share the yaml file where you are referring this 'SecretProviderClass`, presumably where this line 49 is.

Comment: Hi @rock'nrolla, I just updated the question with yaml file contents after removing secret data.. might not be exact line no: 49.  However, I am trying to get true or false value from ssm parameter and depending upon the value, the container provisioning will be decided

Comment: From what I see, you refer to the `otel_enalbed_status` secret and try to use it in a `helm chart` like condition via `{{- if otel_enalbed_status }}` to decide whether the container named `agent` should be started or not. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes @rock'nrolla. you are right. I am trying to refer otel_enalbed_status for the secret and  deciding the container agent need to be started.

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to work like that. Read the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/integrating_csi_driver.html
around the usage of `Kubernetes Secrets Store CSI Driver` and `SecretProviderClass ` CRD. It allows you to fetch secrets inside Amazon EKS pod(s). The way you're using, I'm not sure how you are authenticating to the AWS Secrets Manager in the first place to be able to fetch the secrets.